# GPS Babel and shapefile output?

Tags: shapefile, convert, gpsbabel

How can I use the mother of all gps conversion tools, [gpsbabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/index.html), to create shapefiles? It reads and writes [almost everything](http://www.gpsbabel.org/capabilities.html). Shapefile is conspicuous by it's absence.

A bit of research turns up that shapefile is intentionally not listed as a supported filetype because *"Shapefiles are not well defined.  They're more free-form than most of the formats we support and often require additional arguments or modification to the source."* -- Robert Lipe, gpsbabel author

However the [same thread](http://gpsbabel.2324879.n4.nabble.com/Shapefile-format-tp6695p6696.html) goes on to say shapefile is *"in the `'-^3'` output and marked 'hidden' for this very reason - it's not practical to treat it as 'just another format' "*

Suppose I'm willing to take my chances, how does one get at the hidden formats?
(`xcsv` is mentioned as well).

Comment: I know this doesn't address your question but exporting in kml and batch converting with arcpy could be a workaround.

Comment: What format is the input?

Comment: @Mapperz oziexplorer waypoints at the moment, but really it could be any format not immediately understandable to gdal/ogr or arcgis/arcpy.

Answer (score 2):

Happy discovery, the favoured conversion tool [ogr2ogr](/questions/tagged/ogr2ogr) has a [gpsbabel driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpsbabel.html), so conversion from a predefined format like OziExplorer or Magellan is as easy as (-f param is optional for shapefile, included for clarity):

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output_folder "auriol ozi track file 008.plt"
```

...with other formats using a colon separated syntax (e.g. read straight from garmin device):

```
ogr2ogr output_folder -al GPSBabel:garmin:usb:
```

For curiosity's sake I'd still like to know how to get the hidden gpsbabel drivers directly though.